# Please help identify this tree species

Tags: identification, trees

I have a young tree (~4Y old), located in Toronto, Ontario, Canada. I do not know what type of tree it is, and would really like help identifying it. I seem to recall, but am not 100% on this, that the garden centre where I bought it said it was native to this region (I had asked them for something that would be hardy and not require too much special care).

Photos of the tree's flowers are below.

A [related question I had asked](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/49927/what-to-do-about-damaged-tree-trunk-bark) shows photos of the trunk and leaves.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flowers and the colour of the leaves which are just beginning to emerge ID it as *Amelanchier*, possibly *A. lamarckii* which tends to form a tree rather than just a large shrub. There are several varieties of  this plant though, so as to the exact variety, hard to say; many are native to North America. https://www.saga.co.uk/magazine/home-garden/gardening/plants/trees/how-to-grow-an-amelanchier

Comment: Yes on the ID. If you're not aware, the tree will get edible dark blue berries, but you'll have to fight the birds for them (they usually win). Glad that the tree is living!

Comment: That sure looks like it! Thanks for the help!